# Bootstrap DateTime Picker -- How to append "00" in place of seconds

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have used this: [bootstrap datetime picker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), which when given a format like `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"`, results like `"2013-12-12 01:12"`, but I want to append `":00"` in place of seconds so that my new date format may become `"2013-12-12 01:12:00"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    weekStart: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    minuteStep: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 1,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    });
</script>
```

I then tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
    format: getFormattedDate(),
    weekStart: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    minuteStep: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 1,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    });

    function getFormattedDate() {
        date = new Date();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear().toString();
        var hour = date.getHour();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();
        return year+'-'+month+'-'+day+" "+"hour"+":"+minute+":"+"00";
    }
</script>
```

I failed to get the Desired output, kindly help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't know am I late or not, but I just encountered this scenario and got very simple workaround for this. You simply need to change your js to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00",
weekStart: 1,
autoclose: 1,
todayBtn: 1,
minuteStep: 1,
startView: 2,
forceParse: 1,
pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
});
```

P.S. I am currently working with Twitter Bootstrap version: 3.1.1.3.
Thanks,

Comment: This works! I can't believe how easy this is! Thank you so much! I never would have thought of this!

Comment: You are welcome. I am pleased I could help you and this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSeconds()`method of JavaScripts Dateobject.

Like this:

```
date.setSeconds(0);
```

Then you can get back 0 Seconds too with `date.getSeconds();`

But as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Efjdq/), getSeconds returns a single 0.

The approach with concatenating 00 to end is right when you want a String as result. If you still need the Date object itself you have to set seconds to 0.

Furthermore there's a little mistake: it's `getHours()`insted of `getHour()`